# Aggregation.group("").sum("") How to write the calculation formula?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, mongotemplate

> This is the Mongo script

```
db.servicer_online_time.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group: {
                _id : "$csId" ,
                totalTime: {
                    $sum: {
                        $multiply: ["$offlineTime", "$onlineTime"]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    ]
);
```

> This is Java code

```
GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group("csId").sum("$multiply: [\"$offlineTime\", \"$onlineTime\"]").as("");
```

**Can the script be written in the "sum()" function? How should I write?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try projecting the fields first by using the **[SpEL `andExpression`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.examples.example5)** in the projection operation and then aggregate the new fields in the group operation:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    project("csId").andExpression("offlineTime * onlineTime").as("timesProduct"),
    group("csId").sum("timesProduct").as("totalTime")
);
```